# Equating a column in a database with equal rows using SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

**Table structure:**

```
uid       : integer
answer_id : integer
```

I need to run a query which will show me which uid's have the same answers as other uid's. So for example, here's some test data:

```
answer_id   uid
1           555
4           555
7           555
10          555
1           123
5           123
7           123
10          123
```

So we can see from this data that they each answered 3/4 of the questions the same way.

I'm struggling with how to write a query which would show me which uid's match 3/4 or 4/4 of the same answers. Basically I'm trying to find users with 75% (3/4) or greater (4/4) similar answers.

This is part of a Ruby on Rails application, so I have the models all built [User, UserAnswers etc..] but I'm assuming this will just be a SQL query, not necessarily a part of ActiveRecord

Comment: Out of curiosity - Wouldn't there be a high number of false positives where test takers had chosen correct answers?

Comment: There are no correct answers - it's not an actual test, just a series of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query show the number of answers every user has in common with each other:

```
declare @uid int

select
  ans1.uid as user1,
  ans2.uid as user2,
  count(*)
from 
  ans ans1 inner join ans ans2
  on ans1.answer_id = ans2.answer_id
     and ans1.uid <> ans2.uid
where uid = @uid
group by user1, user2
having count(*)>0
```

This also shows the number of questions each user has answered:

```
 select
  ans1.uid as user1,
  ans2.uid as user2,
  count(distinct ans1.answer_id) as total1,
  count(distinct ans2.answer_id) as total2,
  sum(case when ans1.answer_id = ans2.answer_id then 1 else 0 end) as common
from 
  ans ans1 inner join ans ans2 on ans1.uid <> ans2.uid
group by user1, user2
having count(*)>0
```

(this second query can be very slow)

Comment: I would like to add `having count(*) > 0` to the end :)

Comment: This seems pretty close to what I'm going for. I don't need user2 as I'll be filtering out the current user. I just need the users who match the current user, so I've tweaked it a bit.

Comment: So basically I would need the result set to be just a column for uid, and a column for the count. When I tweak this query to try and do that, the counts get way off. Assuming because I'm grouping wrong?

Comment: @jack to make both query work with one uid known already, you can always put a `WHERE ans1.uid = 123` condition before group by. It should work and it should be logically correct, but as Gordon Linoff said it could be also be inefficient, so i'm still thinking if it can be improved...

Answer (score 1):

FThiella's answer works.  However, doing a cartesian product join is unnecessary.  The following version produces the same counts, without such a complicated join:

```
select ans1.uid as user1,
       ans2.uid as user2,
       max(ans1.numanswers) as total1,
       max(ans2.numanswers) as total2,
       count(*) as common
from (select a.*, count(*) over (partition by uid) as numanswers,
      from UserAnswers a
     ) ans1 inner join
     (select a.*, count(*) over (partition by uid) as numanswers
      from UserAnswers a
     ) ans2
     on ans1.uid <> ans2.uid and
        ans1.answer_id = ans2.answer_id
group by ans1.uid, ans2.uid
```

As with that other answer, this does not include pairs of users that have no answers in common.

Comment: I wouldn't need to know the two users who watch, I would be matching the current user against other similar users, so I'd just need to return the uid's and the count. I wasn't able to get this code to work though.

Comment: Only looking at one user makes the cross join less of an issue, assuming the query engine optimizes the SQL correctly.  I fixed a couple of typos in the query, so it should work.

Comment: Still getting syntax errors. The name of the table is UserAnswers. Your aliasing of the tables is confusing me, so I'm not sure which query should call the actual table or which is joining a subquery? Confused.